# How to show only the articles from current category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I want to show only the articles from current category, where I am at the moment. I wrote code for a look of every post. I use plugin Advanced Custom Fields, which can create more fields for new post in administration.

Now I have this code:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=' ); ?>
<div id="category-window">
<div id="others" style="width:<?php echo $wp_query->post_count*400?>px"> 
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <div class="other-box">
    <div id="other-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div id="other-left"><?php the_field(misto); ?><br><?php the_field(rok); ?></div>
    <div id="other-right"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . '<br>';} ?></div>
    <div id="other-line"></div>
    <div id="other-about"><?php the_field(dej); ?></div>
    <div id="other-gallery">
      <a class="other-photo fancybox" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_field(obrazek1); ?>">
    <img src="<?php the_field(obrazek1); ?>" style="width: 85px; height: 50px;">
      </a>
      <a class="other-photo fancybox" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_field(obrazek2); ?>">
    <img src="<?php the_field(obrazek2); ?>" style="width: 85px; height: 50px;">
      </a>
      <a class="other-photo fancybox" rel="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_field(obrazek3); ?>">
    <img src="<?php the_field(obrazek3); ?>" style="width: 85px; height: 50px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    </div><?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And the problem is just in the first line, I have no idea, what to write behind "cat=", when I want to do it automatically. For example when I am in category "cars", it automatically show only the articles from this category.

Thank you for every help :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
<?php

$postid = get_the_ID();
$catid = get_the_category( $postid );

?>
```

That should get you the cat id.